# Kivy - Extract and group common parameters in KV file like "id" in CSS

Tags: kivy

I'm looking for a way not to repeat the parameters if they are the same for a couple of items.
Here is an example... three times same parameter repeated for the lines under 3 text inputs.

```
            TextInput:
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 42
                multiline:False
                font_size: 32
                foreground_color: (0.1,0.8,1,1)
                background_color: (25/255,26/255,25/255,0)
                thickness: 1
                canvas.after:
                    Color:
                        rgb: .75, .75, .75
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.x, self.y
                        size: self.width-20, self.thickness
            TextInput:
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 42
                multiline:False
                font_size: 32
                foreground_color: (0.1,0.8,1,1)
                background_color: (25/255,26/255,25/255,0)
                thickness: 1
                canvas.after:
                    Color:
                        rgb: .75, .75, .75
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.x, self.y
                        size: self.width-20, self.thickness
            TextInput:
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 42
                multiline:False
                font_size: 32
                foreground_color: (0.1,0.8,1,1)
                background_color: (25/255,26/255,25/255,0)
                thickness: 1
                canvas.after:
                    Color:
                        rgb: .75, .75, .75
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.x, self.y
                        size: self.width-20, self.thickness
```

The main goal is to shorten and optimize the code by grouping parameters and call them when needed, like id in CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Create your own class, give it a kv rule that contains the repeated components, and then use that class.

You can do this dynamically in kv:

```
            <YourTextInput@TextInput>:
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 42
                multiline:False
                font_size: 32
                foreground_color: (0.1,0.8,1,1)
                background_color: (25/255,26/255,25/255,0)
                thickness: 1
                canvas.after:
                    Color:
                        rgb: .75, .75, .75
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.x, self.y
                        size: self.width-20, self.thickness
```

If you want to modify any of these for each YourTextInput, you can create a property of YourTextInput that its rule references, then something like:

```
YourTextInput:
    your_property: some_value
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I nest a set of code lines under <YourTextInput@TextInput>
But how do I call that set later in KV code when I need it?